# Can't use Rviz plugin ObjectSegmentation object_segmentation_gui (interactive object segmentation)

Tags: ros, rviz, object-detection, rviz-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*ROS Fuerte*  
PR2 Gazebo

I'm testing PR2 Interactive Object Detection. When I add try to add a plugin to Rviz,  
 the **ObjectSegmentation** plugin from **object_segmentation_gui**,  
 Rviz segfaults and dies (see backtrace below).

The segfault is almost identical if using stereo camera or Kinect, so you can ignore the line "withDisparityChecked".

Also, when I tick the box to enable "interactive" (object segmentation) mode, the pop-up doesn't load, because it's not working I guess...

Funny thing, this pop-up worked the first time I tested PR2 Interactive Object Detection... now I realize it's broken.

Does anyone have some suggestions please?

cheers, 
David.

Segfault: 
[image: image description]

Backtrace: 
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52336/can%27t-use-rviz-plugin-objectsegmentation-object_segmentation_gui-(interactive-object-segmentation)/) by [dbworth](https://answers.ros.org/users/2571/dbworth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1103 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Interactive Object Segmentation plugin is highly experimental, research code. Unfortunately, we are not able to actively support this version.

The version here might be more promising:

http://ros.org/wiki/bosch_object_segmentation_gui

But you'd have to contact the authors for more details on its current status.

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0